# Pandas slice string based on str.find as position to start and stop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe that looks like this

```
commands
*client interface       : Eth-Trunk45.2903 is up
*client interface       : Eth-Trunk46.2620 is up
*client interface       : Eth-Trunk46.2988 is up
*client interface       : Eth-Trunk55.1703 is up
*client interface       : Eth-Trunk55.1704 is up
*client interface       : GigabitEthernet4/1/12.102 is up
```

how can I slice the string and get the output as below.

```
commands
Eth-Trunk45.2903
Eth-Trunk46.2620
Eth-Trunk46.2988
Eth-Trunk55.1703
Eth-Trunk55.1704
GigabitEthernet4/1/12.102
```

I try

```
df['commands'] = df['commands'].str.slice(start=df['commands'].str.find(':'), stop=df['commands'].str.find(' is'))
```

but this only return me nan value.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get values between values:

```
df['commands'] = df['commands'].str.extract(r":(.+) is", expand=False)
print (df)
                     commands
0            Eth-Trunk45.2903
1            Eth-Trunk46.2620
2            Eth-Trunk46.2988
3            Eth-Trunk55.1703
4            Eth-Trunk55.1704
5   GigabitEthernet4/1/12.102
```

Your solution is possible in [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html), because pandas slicing working only with integers same for all column:

```
df['commands'] = df['commands'].apply(lambda x: x[x.find(': ') + 1: x.find(' is ')])
print (df)
                     commands
0            Eth-Trunk45.2903
1            Eth-Trunk46.2620
2            Eth-Trunk46.2988
3            Eth-Trunk55.1703
4            Eth-Trunk55.1704
5   GigabitEthernet4/1/12.102
```

---

```
print (df['commands'].str.slice(26, 42))
0    Eth-Trunk45.2903
1    Eth-Trunk46.2620
2    Eth-Trunk46.2988
3    Eth-Trunk55.1703
4    Eth-Trunk55.1704
5    GigabitEthernet4
Name: commands, dtype: object
```